# CompositeSubscription leaks memory when using new thread for subscribing to Observable

Tags: android, memory-leaks, rx-java, observable, rx-android

We have a memory leak in our Android app when subscribing to Observable on non-main thread and adding that Observable to CompositeSubscriptions. This is the block of code causing the memory leak:

```
            mSubscriptions.add(Observable.just(imageBytes)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .map(bytes -> {
                    YuvImage yuvimage = new YuvImage(bytes, ImageFormat.NV21, mPreviewWidth, mPreviewHeight, null);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    yuvimage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, mPreviewWidth, mPreviewHeight), 100, baos); // Where 100 is the quality of the generated jpeg
                    byte[] jpegArray = baos.toByteArray(); ...
                })
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(result -> {
                    ...
                }, error -> Timber.e(error)));
    }
```

The memory used inside map is never freed (unless we call CompositeSubscriptions.clear()). There is no memory leak if everything is done on the main thread or if we do not add the Observable to our CompositeSubscription. Either solution is not an option. Please advise how to do this in a proper way so we don't run out of memory.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure whether I understand correct but if you do not manage properly with subscribing you can always get memory leak from application.

Fist of all - you should not use `Schedulers.newThread()` because it generates new thread every time when you subscribe to observable. Instead of using `newThread()` you should use `Schedulers.io()`. It takes pool of thread which are available now.

Second of all - you should show how you manage subscriptions.

```
onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState){
subscriptions.add(...);
}

onPause(){
subscriptions.unsubscribe();
subscriptions.clear();
}
```

If you need to recognise subscription which should be unsubscribed you can use a simple `Map<String, Subscription> map` where you put

```
map.put("TAG_FOR_SUBSCRIPTION", yourSubscription)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. We do use schedulers, newThread is just an example here. Memory leak happens whether we use our own schedulers, ones provided by rx library or new thread. We are clearing composite subscriptions according to lifecycle and that's working OK. Block above is called couple of times per second and it handles images  so it's consuming a lot of memory. It's leaking without any lifecycle events, so it's not related. Quick fix would be clearing each subscription to this observable in onCompleted but that is not fixing the root cause.

Comment: I would like to know why memory is not being freed by GC when we do this on non-main thread and it works perfectly when we do it on main thread.

Comment: `onCompleted` event is risky because you can not be sure that this event will be invoked always.

Comment: Have you used memory dump to recognise which object keeps reference?